# Unable to upload form data and file contents on submit

Tags: file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am attempting to use jQuery-File-Upload for showing the preview of the uploaded image. This is working fine. The code for file upload is as shown below

```
$('#Image').fileupload({
    url : "/FileUpload/Upload",
    autoupload:false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        gm.layout.loaderOpen(); //open loader 
        data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log("done")
        if (data.response().jqXHR.status === 200)
            $('#processImage').attr('src', data.response().jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    always: function (e, data) {
        gm.layout.loaderClose(); 
    }
})
```

However apart from the image preview the form also has other fields which the user fills up and then submits the form. Now I am trying to use ajax to submit and collect the data by serialzing the form

```
var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: "{url}",
           data: formData,
           contentType: false,
           processData:false,
           success: function (data) {
              alert("whatever");
           }

     });
```

This ajax submit fails as long as I have the fileupload for the html input control. With the file upload the multimedia data doesn't reach the server on submit

However, in the absence of fileupload for the same control, everything works fine and I can get the file content on the server.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?